# Div layout is preventing the conversion from vertical scroll to horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this: https://github.com/koggdal/scroll-converter to convert vertical scroll to horizontal, but when I try to implement it onto my code, the vertical scrolling is not being converted to horizontal. I am including the script correctly and I am initializing the script correctly as well, that's not the issue. There has to be some problem with the layout of either #horizontalcontainer or #scrolling-wrapper that is preventing this to work correctly.

Here is a JSFiddle with my code, do you see where I may be going wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/mwdhvzn8/

```
<div id="horizontalcontainer">
  <div id="scrolling-wrapper">
    <div class="videocard1">
      <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    </div>
    <div class="videocard">
      <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    </div>
    <div class="videocard">
      <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    </div>
    <div class="videocard">
      <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    </div>
    <div class="videocard">
      <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="scroll-converter.min.js"></script>
<script>
  (function() {

    scrollConverter.activate();

  }());

</script>    

    #horizontalcontainer {
    z-index: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    }

    #scrolling-wrapper {
      overflow-x: auto;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 60vh;
      width: 100vw;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      -ms-overflow-style: none;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }

    .videocard1 {
      padding-left: 2.5%;
      padding-right: 2.5%;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      width: 46%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    .videocard {
      padding-right: 2.5%;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      width: 46%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Preloaded with jQuery here : https://jsfiddle.net/bilelh/uqrhadgy/  But you still can load Javascript Frameworks when you click near the script to choose the loading method too...

Comment: This fiddle is using your plugin,jquery and bootstrap (all at left near Resources...) . Your initial code works when you click on the wrapper. Can you show us your expected layout because of the #scrolling-wrapper and all those paddings here and there? in #horizontalcontainer there is position: fixed; May be that could (temporary) help : shorturl.at/aCFGO

Comment: @Bilel Thank you for looking into this, I really appreciate it. The expected layout is exactly as it is in my original fiddle as I need everything to be responsive and position as so. Here is an updated fiddle with my original code along with the correct plugin resource that you provided (I don't believe I need bootstrap for this, so I left that out, but if you do believe I need it, please do explain why). I thought the fixed position may be the culprit as well, but removing it still does not fix the issue. Not sure what in the world it could be... https://jsfiddle.net/ynfe2bx0/

Comment: There are extra paddings and there is a Google code (youtube) who iterfers too! https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952 . I'm ready to help when you show us a working embeded videos... Because after solving that first, you may discover other issues with your plugin. What's the priority here? Your layout, youtube or that plugin ? :)

Comment: @Bilel I've only removed the ending of the YouTube embed URLs because they are not at all applicable to the question. Here is a JSFiddle with 'working' embedded videos :) https://jsfiddle.net/mwdhvzn8/     If the padding is what is causing the plugin to not work, can you demonstrate how it needs to be revised in order to not prevent the plugin from correctly working? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout expects Horizontal scrolling on an sub-element of the page. The '#scrolling-wrapper' here.

After reading the plugin code, at first sight, there were  no compatibility issues that are except (Google code is noticing to event handler as 'passive'...) which is not a big deal.
But it's already been reported [here](https://github.com/koggdal/scroll-converter/issues/7) that this plugin wouldn't handle scrolling into an element.

So I suggest, you choose an alternative like [jQuery Mouse Wheel](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel).
It's Better working on [jSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bilelh/2gecwupn/) or on a self-hosted environment.
And here is your Layout using it :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#scrolling-wrapper").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
    
      event.preventDefault();

   });
});
```

```css
#horizontalcontainer {
  z-index: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#scrolling-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 100vw;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.videocard1 {
  padding-left: 2.5%;
  padding-right: 2.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 46%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.videocard {
  padding-right: 2.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 46%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.ifrclass{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.divpad{
    /*padding:56.25% 0 0 0;*/
    /*position:relative;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <div id="horizontalcontainer">
      <div id="scrolling-wrapper">
        <div class="videocard page ">  
          <div class="divpad">  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" class="ifrclass" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>        
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="videocard page ">  
          <div class="divpad">  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" class="ifrclass" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>        
         </div>
        </div>        
        <div class="videocard page ">  
          <div class="divpad">  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" class="ifrclass" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>        
         </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="videocard page ">  
          <div class="divpad">  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM" class="ifrclass" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>        
         </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
```

[UPDATE] Another alternative plugin called [jQuery Custom Scrollbar](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin) gives more controls on Mouswheel and scrolling events and it seems that it took care of exceptions on OSX magic trackpad/mouse.

On the main [script](https://html5up.net/uploads/demos/ethereal/assets/js/main.js) of [ETHEREAL](https://html5up.net/uploads/demos/ethereal/) theme made by HTML5UP, you can see in a clear and commented code and test how it handles mousewheel normalization and you could inspire from it's layout which is similar to your expected result.

Please Notice that I removed the padding on your iframes! That could fit in your final layout. But they look displaced here...

Comment: This is great, thank you very much! I was unaware that the original plugin was not able to scroll into an element. The only issue I am noticing with this jQuery Mouse Wheel plugin is that when I'm using a trackpad to scroll, the conversion for the scrolling speed is way too fast and uncontrollable. I'm assuming it works fantastic with a mouse wheel, but for users with a trackpad, the speed is way off. Am I doing something wrong / is there a work around for users that will be using a trackpad rather than a mouse wheel? FWIW the scroll speed here (https://hotdot.pro) works great with a trackpad.

Comment: Well that's another long story :)

For years they have been discussing this here https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel/issues/36
 I think it's solved. 
. I can't test it but here is an interesting tool to use :
https://github.com/promo/wheel-indicator

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! When trying the JSFiddle in Chrome & Firefox though, the scroll conversion unfortunately doesn't seem to be working at all :(

Comment: Sorry I don't use a trackpad... On windows, Using Chrome with a mouse using jQuery mousewheel it works when you click in the wrapper. I suggest you read that issues page and try a debounce()

Comment: I see. It looks like this (https://github.com/promo/wheel-indicator) link is the fix to the trackpad/wheel-with-inertia issue, but I am unsure how to use it within your JSFiddle. Do you happen to know the way in which to correctly add this additional plugin to your JSFiddle so it works with trackpads and osx users as well? Thank you again for all your help!

Comment: I'd like to but I can't test it on your environment, I can't even show same results on jSfiddle that I get on a server :) May be because that interferes with their iframes scrolling  too...   I just updated my answer where I mention another plugin and a source you could inspire from..

Comment: Really appreciate all your help. You did solve my original problem, thank you!